# Can Firebase hosting behavior be customized (e.g, redirects) based on Authentication status?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

Can Firebase hosting behavior be customized so that if user is not authenticated Firebase redirects to a URL.

I know this can be done client side but am wondering if there is such a way to add another way to achieve this.

By customizing hosting behavior I mean what it has been explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) to perform dynamic processing based on state set in a specially-named `__session` cookie, but there is no built-in way to do this based on client-side Auth state. In addition, even if you use a Cloud Function, exact-match static content (e.g. I have a file `/foo.html` and I go to `/foo.html`) supersedes rewrites and will *always* serve content.

If you'd like to see authorization as a first-class feature of Firebase Hosting, I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).